# unable to connect to VM using SSH and unable to connect deployed MSSQL container in VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, cloud

can anyone help me on below issue.

I have added inbound rules with high priority, but still i am unable to communicate with MSSQL (1433) container deployed on Linux VM and unable to ssh.

getting below error

Network connectivity blocked by security group rule: DefaultRule_DenyAllInBound

Answer (score 0):

Azure creates a default Networking inbound port rule to DenyAllInbound; it does exactly what it says, which is Deny all incoming traffic to the VM.

Go to Settings --> Networking on the VM in the Azure portal and you can then create an allow rule at a higher priority to allow inbound access to port 1433 (I'd be very careful where you open it up to though - a source of 'Any' will invite trouble as people will bombard it).

This document may be helpful: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtual-network/diagnose-traffic-filter-problem